# User shows no results in shell

Tags: python, django, shell

When I am running `python manage.py` shell and I run the following commands, I get this result. What strikes me as odd, is that I have created 2 users in my website that can join groups.

```
>>> from accounts.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

**accounts/models.py**:

```
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

However, when I run these commands below, I get the results I want.

```
>>> from groups.models import GroupMember
>>> GroupMember.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<GroupMember: test2>, <GroupMember: test2>, <GroupMember: test1>
```

**groups/models.py**:

```
class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_groups')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('group', 'user')
```

I have:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

In both models

Could someone please explain to me why this happens? 
Running on `python 3.5` in `django 1.11`

Comment: You appear to have two different models files: `accounts/models.py` and `groups/models.py`.  Is `User` defined in both files, or only one?

Comment: @JohnGordon I edited the question to include your answer. but i believe so. I have:


'from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()'

in both models

Comment: rule of thumb : never create model classes which conflict with default django models. django `auth` also has `User`

Comment: How is `User` defined within `groups/models.py`?  Is it a separate class within that file, or is it imported from somewhere else?

Comment: I just rewatched the tutorial i was following that im trying to build off of and they say that when you ---from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model--- and ---User = get_user_model()--- that the user model comes in with with auth part. atleast whats what i am understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to subclass the User model, the preferred way is to subclass AbstractUser and change the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting to point to your new User model, as explained at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Since you subclassed User and not AbstractUser, what probably happened is that Django created a one-to-one-mapping between your User and Django's built-in User (i.e., two tables exist). Since you probably didn't change AUTH_USER_MODEL, the users you created were then created as Django's built-in User, but not your User. The table containing your User is thus still empty.

Update: I should mention that your way could still work if you're fine with the one-to-one mapping, and are familiar with how multi-table inheritance work (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). If you want to create users from your main site (not from the admin), you can make sure to create an instance of your User too. (If you use django-allauth, there's a signal you could receive.) Or you can create them on demand, but just query Django's model when you want a complete list of users.

Comment: Thank you Ove for your answer and giving me direction for where to look this up! I'll start reading up on this!